# What's the slit and slot on EIS(EUV Imaging Spectrometer) instrument of Hinode?

Tags: the-sun, spectroscopy

There are two slits and two slots on EIS, are they just four types of grating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go back and reference the paper published on this telescope. Specifically it is [Culhane et al. 2007](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-45-34-8674&id=118233#articleBody). This paper talks about the overall telescope, however the paper describing the optics is [Korendyke et al. (2006)](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-45-34-8674&id=118233#articleBody). Unfortunately this optics paper is behind a paywall.

Within the Culhane paper, in section 3, the describe the slit mechanism as

> Exposure times are controlled by a rotating shutter while a slit exchange mechanism can allow selection of four possible apertures — two spectral slits and two spectral imaging slots.

That's about as much detail as they give, except to note in table 1 that the slit and slot widths are 1, 2, 40, and 266 arcsec.

In the Korendyke optics paper, they give a bit more detail.

> Light passing through the slit is dispersed and stigmatically reimaged by the toroidal grating onto two 1024 x 2048 pixel CCD detectors. The focus of the grating can be remotely adjusted with a mechanism. In flight, the mirror will be rotated in ~0.125 arcsec increments about the Y axis [solar north–south (N-S)] to sample different structures of the solar surface with the slit. High-resolution spectroheliograms (raster images) are formed by steadily moving the solar image in fine increments on the spectrograph slit and taking re-peated exposures. An interchange mechanism allows selection among two slits (1 and 2 arc sec wide) and two slots (40 or 266 arc sec wide). The slot observations of the solar disk produce spectrally pure images
>   of large areas of the disk in bright solar emission lines with each exposure. The slot images exhibit a modest spatial blur along the dispersion direction.

For completion, they also include the diagram below of the optics.

[image]

From reading all of this, it appears to me that the various slit/slot widths are designed for taking different types of images/spectra, either of very focused, single-instance areas (such as with the slits) or else of large regions (using the slots).